# Replace a existing HTML link dynamically using js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm using Joomla and use a radio box to select a buy option.
Everything works fine and I'm able to dynamically update the information displayed to the user.

My issue is to update the buy link when they select the option. My current js code to update the front end is:

```
jQuery(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#pricing').text('R'+'<?php echo (int)$opt1_o_price ?>');
$('#savings').text('R'+'<?php echo $opt1_save ?>');
$('#discount').text(Math.round('<?php echo $perc1 ?>')+'%');
}); 
$('.item').on('change',function(){
$('#pricing').text('R'+($(this).data('price')));
$('#savings').text('R'+($(this).data('price')-$(this).data('after')));
$('#discount').text(Math.round(100-
($(this).data('after')/$(this).data('price')*100))+'%');
$('input[name=sku]').val($(this).data('sku'));
```

And the code used to generate the link is:

```
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('my-groupbuy-cart?&task=add_to_cart&id='.$cmgbstore_id).'&option_id=1'; ?>"</a>
```

I am already able to select the ID using "$cmgbstore_id" because it gets loaded when the page loads, but I need to be able to change the "option_id" at the end of the link by using the option they have selected in the radio box. The value will always either be "1", "2" or "3". 
An example of my radio box code is:

```
<div class="product-options">
<div class="option-input">
     <input id="1" type="radio" value= "1" name="product-option" class="radio item" checked="checked" data-sku="1001" data-price="<?php echo (int)$opt1_o_price ?>" data-save="<?php echo (int)$opt1_save?>" data-after="<?php echo (int)$opt1_d_price ?>" />
      </div>
      <label for="1" class="option-detail">
        <span class="option-title"><?php echo $opt1_title ?></span>
        <span class="option-price">R<?php echo $opt1_o_price ?></span>
        <span class="option-was-price">R<?php echo $opt1_d_price ?></span>
        <span class="option-discount">Save R<?php echo $opt1_save .'.00'?></span>
</label>
```

I tried using the append option in js but every time the option changes another buy button gets added. Also it gets added at the end of the page and not where the original buy button was. The code I tried was something like this:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', 'my-groupbuy-cart?&task=add_to_cart&id='+'<?php echo $cmgbstore_id ?>'+'&option_id=1');
link.innerHTML = "BUY NOW";
$('body').append(link);
```

I'm open for suggestions though and would really appreciate any help!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply add an id to your link and modify the href attribute?

Comment: @LioraHaydont Thanks for the quick reply! Would you be able to give an example on how I would do this? EDIT: What I mean is I know how to update the containing text using an id, but how do I change the href attribute?

Comment: Using jquery, its simply `$( selector ).attr('href','http://new/value');`. You just need to wrestle in your selector. Using a unique ID for the buy now button, or finding it by some other data filter.

Comment: Most likely your PHP has already completed its execution by the time the browser receives the HTML and JavaScript; could you please post a snippet of [mcve] code as received by the client, and without the PHP littering it?

Comment: @DavidThomas Please see : [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nbucona8/2/) This was used to adapt and change the information displayed whenever selecting the radio option. What I need now is to change the buy link im using as show above. The buy link Is created using `<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('my-groupbuy-cart?&task=add_to_cart&id='.$cmgbstore_id).'&option_id=1'; ?>"</a>` so I just need some way to update the option ID to the radio box value whenever it gets clicked. Hope this cleared up some confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out using the replies on my initial question.
What I did if someone else needs it: DEMO - https://jsfiddle.net/nbucona8/4/

It was simpler than I thought, but as @IncredibleHat said above I needed to use
`$( selector ).attr('href','http://new/value');`, so I made it:

```
$( "a[name='buy-button']" ).attr("href","/somelink/"+ dealid +"&option_id="+ $(this).attr("value"));
```

It refers back to any `<a>`  element with the name "buy-button" and changes the href to the correct option_id.

So I call the buy link using:

```
<a name="buy-button" href=""> BUY NOW! </a>
```

And whenever the radio box option changes it changes the option_id by using :

```
 $(this).attr("value")
```

at the end of the link.

Thanks to everyone that helped out.